# SSH Connection timed out

Tags: linux, ssh

I have two PC in my network. I want that PC1 have got `ssh` access to PC2. 
On PC2 I have installed `ssh-server`. In PC2 `inet addr:192.168.0.100` . Next I execute on PC1 this command: `ssh root@192.168.0.100` and get error: `Connection timeout`. I'm use Ubuntu 15.04

Why? What I need configure for my task?

**UPD:**

```
sudo netstat -tulpen | grep ":22"

tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          75804       8281/sshd       
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      0          75806       8281/sshd       
udp6       0      0 :::22918                :::*                                0          65985       6596/dhclient
```

**UPD2:**

```
root@v400:/ # ssh -vv ivan@192.168.0.100
OpenSSH_6.4, OpenSSL 1.0.1j 15 Oct 2014
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.0.100 [192.168.0.100] port 22.
debug1: connect to address 192.168.0.100 port 22: Connection timed out
ssh: connect to host 192.168.0.100 port 22: Connection timed out

root@v400:/ # nc 192.168.0.100 22
Failed to connect nc 192.168.0.100:22
```

Comment: Which distro are you using? What have you done so far? Is port 22 being listened on on all interfaces? Please post the output of `sudo netstat -tulpen | grep ":22"`.

Comment: @Ben I updated my question

Comment: Okay, ssh is running. Please give the relevant output of the following commands: `ssh -vv root@192.168.0.100` and `nc 192.168.0.100 22`. The first one is ssh with more information printed, and the second (netcat) will just try to establish *any* connection.

Comment: @Ben I updated my question

Comment: Did you install ufw or any other firewall software? Are both PCs in the same network?

Comment: Thank you. Problem had benn in ufw. I'm disabled ufw and all works now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As came out in comments, disable ufw. Uncomplicated Firewall (ufw) will by default block ssh connections as well.